# Docusign SDK C# Resend envelope with different email body and subject

Tags: c#, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am using the following code to resend an envelope (to the same email address as the previous) for which I want to update the email body and/or subject.

```
            var prevSigner = envelopesApi.ListRecipients(account_id, docusigncriteria.envelope_id).Signers[0];
            Signer signer1 = new Signer
            {
                Email = docusigncriteria.signerEmail,
                Name = docusigncriteria.signerName,
                RecipientId = prevSigner.RecipientId,
                RoutingOrder = "1",
                ClientUserId = docusigncriteria.signerName,
                EmbeddedRecipientStartURL = "SIGN_AT_DOCUSIGN",
                EmailNotification = new RecipientEmailNotification
                {
                    EmailSubject = "Custom email subject for signer 1",
                    EmailBody = "Custom email body for signer 1"
                }
            };

            List<CarbonCopy> ccList = new List<CarbonCopy>();
            for (int i = 0; i < docusigncriteria.ccEmails.Length; i++)
            {
                ccList.Add(new CarbonCopy
                {
                    Email = docusigncriteria.ccEmails[i],
                    Name = docusigncriteria.ccNames[i] ?? "To Whom it May Concern",
                    RecipientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    RoutingOrder = "1",
                    DeliveryMethod = "email",
                    EmailNotification = new RecipientEmailNotification
                    {
                        EmailSubject = "Custom email subject for signer 1",
                        EmailBody = "Custom email body for signer 1"
                    }
                });
            }
            Recipients rec = new Recipients
            {
                Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1 },
                CarbonCopies = ccList,
            };
            var recSummary = envelopesApi.UpdateRecipients(account_id, docusigncriteria.envelope_id, rec, new EnvelopesApi.UpdateRecipientsOptions() { resendEnvelope = "true" });
```

However only the CC recipients see the new email body/subject text. The signer receives and email with the original sent email body/subject.

Answer (score 0):

Need to call the api Update method with the specified changes. Then, calling the UpdateRecipients method resends the envelope email with the expected changes to email subject and body.

````
env.EmailSubject = "Updated Email Subject";
env.EmailBlurb = "Here is the updated body of the email.";
envelopesApi.Update(accountId, envelopeId, env);```
````